# getting error when I try to change the response header using JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I added this line to change the response header in JSP `<c:set target="${pageContext.response}" property="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>`.. I am getting error like this..

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Caused by:

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:202)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.search_jsp._jspx_meth_c_set_2(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.search_jsp:397)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.search_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.search_jsp:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:110)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:536)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:915)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

And this is the below jsp code where I added that line.

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="search" uri="/kit" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="solr" uri="/kit/solr" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="workflow" uri="/kit/workflow" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="/kit/security" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="widget" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/widgets" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="visualization" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/visualizations" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="client" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/client" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<search:twigkit mode="PRODUCTION">
    <solr:platform host="http://stg.xyz.com:8800/lucene/master/" 
        defaultQuery="*:*" defaultFacets="docType,imType,pLine,originator,technology"/>
    <search:query var="query" parameters="*" 
        fields="*" />
    <search:response var="response" platform="${platform}" query="${query}">
        <workflow:processor name="kit.linguistics.processors" title="title" summary="text" />   
    </search:response>
</search:twigkit>

<c:set var="res" value="http://stg.xyz.com:8800/dps/"/>
<c:set var="dpsURL" value="http://stg.xyz.com:8800/dps"/>
<c:set target="${pageContext.response}" property="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Search :: ${query.value.display}</title>
    <client:head/>
    <script src="${res}dpsjsclient/dps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${res}dpsjsclient/dps-main.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpServletResponse`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) indeed doesn't have a `setAccess-Control-Allow-Origin()` method. Even when it has one, setting/changing the headers while you're basically inside the response body is also not always guaranteed to work (JSP is basically part of the response body!). You'll only risk seeing `IllegalStateException: response already committed` in the server logs.

You want to set the response headers far before the response is committed. The best place is using a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). Create a class which `implements Filter` and do the job in the `doFilter()` method.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Map this filter on the desired URL-pattern.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for reply..Now I understand. And how can I add this servlet code in my JSP..... And one thing more.. As I am working locally and I wanted to get the response back from some different server.. so this will work?? And that's what I want to do..

Comment: Just exactly as I said. Create a class which implements Filter. JSP isn't the right place for this. Or you must be accepting the fallback to *scriptlets*. Put the line in the very top of the JSP then, far before any character is been emitted to the response body.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks for reply.. But Still I wasn't able to understand.. I undertsand that part of creating a class filter and all... But how can i add this in my JSP code.. as I have to use JSP.. So that means somehow I have to add this filter code in my JSP. Can you provide the example of adding filter class in my JSP code above.. That will be great help for me...

Comment: You need to map it on the desired URL pattern. Assuming that you're still on a pre-Servlet-3.0 container, then you need to map it in `web.xml`. For example `<url-pattern>/foo.jsp</url-pattern>` when you want to hook on a specific JSP only. Or `<url-pattern>/somepath/*</url-pattern>` when you want it to hook on all requests on `/somepath`. The blueish "filter" part in my answer is a link. Click it for a complete declaration example.

Comment: @BalusC, Now I understand.. So according to you.. Create a Servlet for filter.. And apply the changes in web.xml file.. I did the same way.. And in the web.xml file I wrote like this.  `<filter>
   <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>AccessFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`
And * means it will apply for all the servlets and JSP. But when I checked my response header.. that header is not coming yet..

Comment: A filter is not the same as a servlet. You just need to create a filter, not a servlet. As to the problem: Java classes needs to be placed in a package in order to be visible for other classes which are in a package (the servletcontainer itself, for example). If that doesn't solve the problem, read the servletcontainer's startup logs for errors.

Comment: @BalusC, yes I created only the filter not the servlet in the same way.. And also when the jsp page gets loaded.. There is a button on that page and after clicking on that button, I am calling jQuery to get the response back from another domain server. I was not able to see any error in the logs..   :(

Comment: That header has to be set by the another domain.

Comment: @BalusC, so that means it is not possible with this solution as you told me.. :(

Comment: No. If that was possible, it would be a security hole and that whole header would have been totally pointless. Note that your question wasn't formulated as such that you'd like to set it on the HTTP response which is returned from another domain, so my answer is technically not wrong.

Comment: @BalusC, so that means it has to be done on the sever side.. by modifying the header in httpd.conf file on the apache server to 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*".. Am I right??

Comment: It definitely needs to be done in the server side. If the client was able to change it, it would have been a **huge** security hole. I've even posted a JSP/Servlet targeted answer as to how to set it in the server side. However, in this case you need to do it on the other domain, there where the ajax response is supposed to originate. Do you have full control over the content served by the other domain? It needs to be set over there. How to do it depends fully on the webserver/appserver used and the supported programming languages.